# Why are the temporary registers split in the MIPS ISA?

Tags: mips, cpu-registers, calling-convention, abi, instruction-set

I'm currently taking a class that covers the MIPS ISA and one thing that I noticed is the split in temporary registers:

[image]

Temporary registers `$t0` to `$t7` are stored in `$8` to `$15`, but `$t8` and `$t9` are stored in `$24` and `$25`. Why is this? Why not make the temporary registers consecutive?

Comment: easier for assembler perhaps? since the low bits of the register number is now the same in both columns

Comment: Perhaps an earlier version of the register layout used or reserved registers $24-$25 for some other purpose (e.g. reserving them for the kernel) but it turned out that they weren't needed for that purpose.

Comment: maybe you'll get better answers about historical things in [retrocomputing.se]

Comment: unless the author(s) of this convention are present at SO then there is no answer.  this is in general not an SO question.  too broad, no answer.

Comment: @old_timer I disagree. It's neither too broad, nor does it require the author to be present.

Comment: @BoraM.Alper While I agree that this question is not too broad, it is necessarily going to invite opinion based and speculative answers, and therefore the question is off topic for SO. Nobody except the original designer(s) can really know the reason for sure, but they haven't responded to this question in over nine months, and nor has anyone else.

Comment: This should not have been closed.